# Spring MVC or Spring Boot for wildfly deployment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, wildfly

I am converting Java web project into Spring Project. (10 JSP and 5 controllers connecting to DB)

We are using Wildfly server for deployment.

Is there any use of creating Spring Boot project (though i have facilities like actuators, starters etc.)

or

Is it fine to create Spring MVC Project and deploy the war in Wildfly as i am not using any container here and spring boot project will be an overhead? Basically i am finding why should i use spring boot here?

Comment: The fact that you use Spring BOot (and its auto-config) doesn't mean you cannot deploy to wildfly, you can perfectly well create a regular WAR file with Spring Boot and still get the auto-config, actuator etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Yes i can deploy the same but isn't it meant for docker type containers only?

Comment: It'll work fine with war deployment, but it is typically a lot more headache than a jar launcher.

Comment: No it isn't meant for docker type deployments only. As stated you can still build a war, benefit from auto-config, actuators and what more in a traditional environment. Note that not all properties (especially those related to server configuration) don't apply anymore because you now have an external instead of embedded server.

Answer (score 0):

it depends.

Spring boot is just **SpringMVC + Tomcat** in one JAR (very simplified definition, I know).

If you have an existing and working Wildfly Server, use it. Compile your web app as WAR an deploy it. You will have also better configuraiton, server update and server bugfixing possibilities. At least that was in my case, as my team mates had a lot of experience with Wildfly.

We are using SpringBoot for small pure REST (micro)services (without HTML, JSP), since they are fast to implement and to deploy (just run a jar file). All of these applications have their own Tomcat server - with own PORT. If you want a new Tomcat version you have to recompile your application. This could be a disadvantage (but not realy).

Comment: Yes i have seen Spring Boot application for Rest Services only and deployed in Docker. Never seen apps deployed in servers. So bit confused wherther to use or not

Comment: It is not *deployed* in Docker, it runs in Docker. As a springboot application with its own tomcat server.

Comment: @fatherazrael I would say try both and gain experience. You'll see which solution is better for you.

Comment: Spring Boot offers different options for deployent JAR/WAR embedded or not embedded. So to state that Spring Boot is "just Spring MVC and Tomcat in one jar" is way to simplistic and simply not true. And you can use it perfectly well as a regular WAR and still benefit from auto-config.

Comment: @M.Deinum My focus was on the question _"why should i use spring boot here"_. Since it is a finished application including configuration, db connection etc. auto-config is totaly irrelevant in his case. and have also pointed out that it is a very simplified definition. if you know the solution, write your own answer.

Comment: He isn't converting a Spring project he is converting a plain Web project to Spring and ask if it is useful to use Spring Boot instead of plain Spring in the conversion. At least that is what I make from the question.